# Помогите разобраться с кодом

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    static int noOfNodes;
    int suffixNode;

    Node () : 
        suffixNode(-1) {};

    ~Node() {
       //  cout << "destroying node " << id << endl;

    }
};
#endif
```

Вопросы:

1) Что изменится, если static int превратить в int и перенести в private

2) Что здесь происходит:

```
Node () : 
        suffixNode(-1) {};
```

Comment: пытаться изучать язык в SO -  плохая идея...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если убрать `static`, это поле класса станет доступным только после создания объекта класса. (сейчас оно доступно даже без единого объекта, его можно получить: `Node::noOfNodes`, то есть, непосредственно из самого класса). Однако, так как этому полю не присвоено значение, будет получена ошибка. При добавлении `private` поле класса станет доступно только методам класса.
2. Указанный Вами код является конструктором класса и присваивает полю `suffixNode` значение -1 при создании объекта класса. Это аналогично тому, если бы было написано:

   ```
   Node ()
   {
       suffixNode = -1;
   }
   ```

Comment: *"код является конструктором класса и присваивает полю"* - срого говоря, не присваивает полю, а инициализирует поле...